# How do i iterate through a table and print out the values of the columns Selenium Webdriver Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am having a problem in iterating through a html table and output the values from column 2 of each row.  Column 2 which is td[2] in row 1 has the value "Name", column 2 in row 2 has the value "Address" and so on.
I am trying to print out the values to the console.

My Python webdriver code is:

```
    # Get the table
table_xpath = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 'html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[5]/div/div[3]/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody')
# Get the rows from the table
rows = table_xpath.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr.GAT4PNUFG.GAT4PNUMG")
# Get the columns (all the column 2)
cols = rows.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[2]
for i in cols:
    print cols.text
```

The error i get is:

```
  File "C:\Webdriver\ClearCore 501\Pages\data_objects_saved_page.py", line 87, in verify_variables_created
cols = rows.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[2]
```

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find_elements'

The HTML snippet is:

```
     <table cellspacing="0" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;">
    <colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="GAT4PNUFG GAT4PNUMG" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="0">
            <td class="GAT4PNUEG GAT4PNUGG GAT4PNUHG GAT4PNUNG">
            <td class="GAT4PNUEG GAT4PNUGG GAT4PNUNG">
                <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-324" style="outline-style:none;">
                    <span class="linkhover" title="Name" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;color:#00A;cursor:pointer;">Name</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="GAT4PNUEG GAT4PNUGG GAT4PNUNG">
            <td class="GAT4PNUEG GAT4PNUGG GAT4PNUNG">
            <td class="GAT4PNUEG GAT4PNUGG GAT4PNUNG">
            <td class="GAT4PNUEG GAT4PNUGG GAT4PNUBH GAT4PNUNG">
        </tr>
        <tr class="GAT4PNUEH" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="1">
            <td class="GAT4PNUEG GAT4PNUFH GAT4PNUHG">
            <td class="GAT4PNUEG GAT4PNUFH">
                <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-324" style="outline-style:none;">
                    <span class="linkhover" title="Address" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;color:#00A;cursor:pointer;">Address</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="GAT4PNUEG GAT4PNUFH">
            <td class="GAT4PNUEG GAT4PNUFH">
            <td class="GAT4PNUEG GAT4PNUFH">
            <td class="GAT4PNUEG GAT4PNUFH GAT4PNUBH">
        </tr>
        <tr class="GAT4PNUFG" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="2">
            <td class="GAT4PNUEG GAT4PNUGG GAT4PNUHG">
            <td class="GAT4PNUEG GAT4PNUGG">
                <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-324" style="outline-style:none;">
                    <span class="linkhover" title="DOB" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;color:#00A;cursor:pointer;">DOB</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="GAT4PNUEG GAT4PNUGG">
            <td class="GAT4PNUEG GAT4PNUGG">
            <td class="GAT4PNUEG GAT4PNUGG">
            <td class="GAT4PNUEG GAT4PNUGG GAT4PNUBH">
        </tr>
        <tr class="GAT4PNUEH" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="3">
            ---
        <tr class="GAT4PNUFG" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="4">       
            ---
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How can i iterate through this table and print out the values in Python, Webdriver please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The developer has put an ID into the table.  I have it working now.  It is printing all the cell values from column 2.  The code is:

```
table_id = self.driver.find_element(By.ID, 'data_configuration_feeds_ct_fields_body0')
rows = table_id.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr") # get all of the rows in the table
    for row in rows:
    # Get the columns (all the column 2)        
    col = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[1] #note: index start from 0, 1 is col 2
    print col.text
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to *iterate over rows*:

```
rows = table_xpath.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr.GAT4PNUFG.GAT4PNUMG")

for row in rows:
    # Get the columns (all the column 2)
    col = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[2]
    print col.text
```

Comment: I am getting nothing output in the console for print col.text.  I have checked my Xpath for the table.  In Firefox it does locate the table so Xpath to the table must be ok.

Comment: Thank you for the updated answer.  I am still getting nothing printed.  I am going to try the 2nd TR as that has a different tag name.  It has <tr class="GAT4PNUFG"  I will see if that one outputs anything.

Comment: The developer is putting ids into the code now.  The table will have an id, hopefully it should work then.  I won't have to use xpath to get the table locator

Comment: @RiazLadhani thanks for the update. Lmk if you'll need help with that later on.

Comment: I have the table id now. id="data_configuration_feeds_ct_fields_body0"

Comment: Hey, I have got it working now.  It is printing all the cell values from column 2 of the table.  The code is: table_id = self.driver.find_element(By.ID, 'data_configuration_feeds_ct_fields_body0')
rows = table_id.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
for row in rows:
col = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[2]
print col.text